# unexpected behavior when combining two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This may be a bug, but it may also be a subtlety of pandas that I'm missing. I'm combining two dataframes and the result's index isn't sorted. What's weird is that I've never seen a single instance of combine_first that failed to maintain the index sorted before.

```
>>> a1
                            X  Y
DateTime                                    
2012-11-06 16:00:11.477563      8        80
2012-11-06 16:00:11.477563      8        63
>>> a2
                        X  Y
DateTime                                   
2012-11-06 15:11:09.006507      1        37
2012-11-06 15:11:09.006507      1        36
>>> a1.combine_first(a2)
                            X  Y
DateTime                                   
2012-11-06 16:00:11.477563      8        80
2012-11-06 16:00:11.477563      8        63
2012-11-06 15:11:09.006507      1        37
2012-11-06 15:11:09.006507      1        36
>>> a2.combine_first(a1)
                            X  Y
DateTime                                    
2012-11-06 16:00:11.477563      8        80
2012-11-06 16:00:11.477563      8        63
2012-11-06 15:11:09.006507      1        37
2012-11-06 15:11:09.006507      1        36
```

I can reproduce, so I'm happy to take suggestions. Guesses as to what's going on are most welcome.

Comment: unrelated comment (I don't know what pandas is), but I read the title as "unexpected behaviour when combining two dataframes *into* pandas" and it made me laugh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `combine_first` function uses `index.union` to combine and sort the indexes. The `index.union` docstring states that it only sorts if possible, so `combine_first` is not necessarily going to return sorted results by design.

For non-monotonic indexes, the `index.union` tries to sort, but returns unsorted results if there is an exception. I don't know if this is a bug or not, but `index.union` does not even attempt to sort monotonic indexes like the datetime index in your example.

I've opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2196), but I guess you should do `a2.combine_first(a1).sort_index()` for any datetime indexes for now.

**Update**:  This bug is now fixed on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually mean to use `.append()`?

Try:-

```
a2.append(a1)
```

`combine_first` is not actually an `append` operation.  See - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html?highlight=combine_first#combining-overlapping-data-sets:-

> A problem occasionally arising is the combination of two similar data
>   sets where values in one are preferred over the other. An example
>   would be two data series representing a particular economic indicator
>   where one is considered to be of “higher quality”. However, the lower
>   quality series might extend further back in history or have more
>   complete data coverage. As such, we would like to combine two
>   DataFrame objects where missing values in one DataFrame are
>   conditionally filled with like-labeled values from the other
>   DataFrame.

while `append` is http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html?highlight=append

> Append columns of other to end of this frame’s columns and index,
>   returning a new object. Columns not in this frame are added as new
>   columns.

Comment: No, I don't mean to use append()